# Vue computed property not recomputing as I would have expected

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to create a generic search component with an event that gets emitted with the search string back to the parent so the parent can actually filter the results.

With the code below why does `computed.filteredDocuments` not recompute when the value of `this.searchCriteria` changes and how can I tweak my code so that it does recompute when `updatedSearchString` is called?

Parent component

```
<template>
  <search :searchCriteria="searchCriteria" @searchString="updatedSearchString" />
  <div v-for="(doc, index) in filteredDocuments" v-bind:key="index">
    <div>{{doc.filename}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import store from '../store/index'
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
// import _ from 'lodash'
import Search from '../components/search'

export default {
  name: 'Parent',
  components: {
    Search: Search
  },
  data () {
    return {
      searchCriteria: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      documents: state => state.documents.items
    }),
    filteredDocuments () {
      console.log('in computed')
      return _(this.documents)
        .filter(this.applySearchFilter)
        .value()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updatedSearchString (searchString) {
      this.searchCriteria = searchString <-- I WOULD HAVE EXPECTED BY UPDATING THIS IT WOULD TRIGGER COMPUTED.FILTEREDDOCUMENTS TO RECOMPUTE
    }
  },
  applySearchFilter (doc) {
    console.log('in applySearchFilter')
    // If no search criteria return everything
    if (this.searchCriteria === null) {
      return true
    }

    if (doc.filename.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchCriteria.toLowerCase())) {
      return true
    }
    return false
  }
}
</script>
```

Child component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <q-search v-model="search" placeholder="Search" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Search',
  props: {
    searchCriteria: { type: String, required: true }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      search: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.search = this.searchCriteria // Clone
  },
  watch: {
    search: function (newVal, oldVal) {
      // If no search criteria return everything
      if (!newVal) {
        this.clearSearch()
      }

      this.$emit('searchString', newVal) <-- THIS EMITS THE SEARCH VALUE TO THE PARENT
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `filteredDocuments` isn't dependent on `searchCriteria`. Only the filter callback function is.

Comment: But since `filteredDocuments` filters with the function `this.applySearchFilter` which uses `this.searchCriteria` i would have expected it to work. It works when I do this all within the same component.

Comment: You should not clone data in. Use a settable computed for searchCriteria in the child. The setter should do the emit. This is probably not the source of your trouble, tho. I don't know why it isn't working for you. Any chance you can make a fiddle that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Looks like `applySearchFilter` is not within your `methods` section here.

Comment: @RoyJ it was all because `applySearchFilter` is not within `methods` as you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

What I ran into turning your example code into a snippet was some of the camel case/kebab case issue: HTML is case-insensitive, so the event should be kebab-case, not camelCase. This example filters as expected.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    searchCriteria: '',
    documents: [{
        filename: 'FirstFile'
      },
      {
        filename: 'SecondFile'
      },
      {
        filename: 'LastOne'
      }

    ]
  },
  methods: {
    updatedSearchString(searchString) {
      this.searchCriteria = searchString
    },
    applySearchFilter(doc) {
      console.log('in applySearchFilter')
      // If no search criteria return everything
      if (this.searchCriteria === null) {
        return true
      }

      if (doc.filename.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchCriteria.toLowerCase())) {
        return true
      }
      return false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredDocuments() {
      console.log('in computed')
      return this.documents
        .filter(this.applySearchFilter)
    }
  },
  components: {
    search: {
      template: '#child-template',
      props: {
        searchCriteria: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        }
      },
      computed: {
        search: {
          get() {
            return this.searchCriteria;
          },
          set(value) {
            this.$emit('search-string', value);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/quasar-extras@latest/material-icons/material-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/quasar-framework@latest/dist/umd/quasar.mat.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/quasar-framework@latest/dist/umd/quasar.mat.umd.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <search :search-criteria="searchCriteria" @search-string="updatedSearchString"></search>
  <div v-for="(doc, index) in filteredDocuments" v-bind:key="index">
    <div>{{doc.filename}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="child-template">
  <div>
    <q-search v-model="search" placeholder="Search" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: camel vs kebab isn't my issue as it's getting into my `updatedSearchString` function. Let me see if i can put a fiddle together

Comment: The problem is computed properties are cached: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods